# Export Exchange emails to Google Apps accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, microsoft

I'm migrating several Exchange email users to a Google Apps for Business account. Some of these users read all their email in the Exchange webmail interface. I'd like to transfer their mail over to Gmail so that no emails are lost.

What is the easiest way to do this? Should I just lead each user through the process of backing up their email to a desktop email client before making the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ['Google Apps migration for Microsoft Exchange'](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration) tool might be right up your alley.

From the website:

> Now you can migrate email, contacts and calendar data from on-premise and hosted 
>   Microsoft® Exchange to Google Apps,
>   whether you have just a few users or
>   tens of thousands.
>
> You can also migrate data from PST
>   files and emails from IMAP servers
>   (Novell® GroupWise®, Cyrus, Dovecot,
>   Courier and Gmail) using this tool.

Looks like they even have some on-demand webinars that will walk you through the process.